# Positive definiteness of a linear combination of semi positive definite matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Assume I have the following condition:
    $M=\sum_{i=1}^N M_i$ is a **positive definite** matrix while $M_i$ is **semi-positive definite** matrix. If we introduce positive integer $\alpha_i>0$ such that $M'=\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i M_i$, my question is that does $M'$ has the same positive definiteness as $M$, or simply, does the $M'$ and $M$ have the same rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive definiteness of $M$ implies positive definiteness of $M'$, as
$$ M' = \alpha M + \sum_{i=1}^N \underbrace{(\alpha_i - \alpha)}_{\ge 0} M_i $$
for 
$$\alpha = \min_{1\le i \le N} \alpha_i > 0.$$

The converse is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have an another question, does the statement holds for the case when $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Well, the serie $M$ and $M'$ need to converge and $\alpha$ need to be positiv. Then, it should work.

Comment: In my case, the $M$ is bounded, that is $m_1 I \leq M\leq m_2 I$, and $\alpha>0$, does it work?

Comment: and does $M'$ converge?

Comment: there is no assumption on $M'$.

Comment: Then you can't split the sum/series, sorry. What assumptions do you have on $\alpha_i$ and $M_i$?

Comment: $\alpha_i>0$ and $M_i$ is semi-positive definite.

Comment: may you assume that $\alpha_i$'s are bounded and $M$ converges absolutely? You need to know that $M'$ exists.

Comment: In fact, in my work, $\alpha_i$ is converging to $0$ when $N \to \infty$, and $M$ is bounded, are those conditions  enough?

Comment: @WangyanLi does the series $M$ converges absolutely? in that case, it is sufficient for $M'$ to converge absolutely.

Comment: No, it doesn't,  $M$ is just bounded, does it sufficiently to make $M'$ is bounded as well ?

Comment: it doesn't even guarantee $M'$ to exist. also if $\alpha_i$ tends to $0$, then $\alpha=0$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.